# How to open Soomla storefront in Spritebuilder?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder, soomla

I have a Spritebuilder project that i want to use with Soomla In App Purchase framework. In Spritebuilder, i have a button with "store" as selector for cccontrol. In Soomla documentation, the code that opens storefront is this:

```
[[StorefrontController getInstance] openStoreWithParentViewController:self]; // 'self' is the calling UIViewController
```

Normally in Xcode, i will do this:

```
- (void)store {
CCScene *storeAssets = [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"StoreAssets"];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:storeAssets];
}
```

For this case, how do i integrate the Soomla code into Spritebuilder since it don't use UIViewController?

```
- (void)store {
//Soomla code
}
```

Comment: ccdirector is the uiviewcontroller of cocos2d

Comment: Storefront is an old product from SOOMLA that is not supported anymore. We're going to opensource it to the community.